# Objective-c: undeclared identifier applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to use code from [this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

I'm a react-native developer, so sorry, probably this is a silly question :)

How do i know where from should i import this method? `applicationDidEnterBackground`

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate) aren't give me answer for this either.

Comment: You may want to be conforms to protocol `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing this:

#### `AppDelegate`

You should implement this method in your `AppDelegate.m`
You can find your app's delegate by looking at `main.m` file and you will something like

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

`AppDelegate` is your app's delegate class.

#### `NSNotificationCenter`

There is a built-in `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification which is declared in `UIApplication.h` and
you can add any kind of object as observer to `NSNotificationCenter`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:{myObserver}
     selector:@selector({myObserverMethod}:) // adding ":" at the end will provide you the sent notification as parameter to your method
     name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
     object:nil];
```

Now you need to implement `{myObserverMethod}:(NSNotification *)notification` in your `{myObserver}` class

```
// MyObserver.m
- (void)myObserverMethod:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIApplication *application = notification.object;
    // Now you can call `[application beginBackgroundTask:]` or etc.
    NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
}
```

**NOTE:** Don't forget that [prior to iOS 9](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/unregistering-nsnotificationcenter-observers-in-ios-9/) you need to call `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:{myObserver}]` when you are done with it!

Comment: okay, that's unexpected... So, how do i pass some arguments into it from another "Cocoa Touch Class" (`.m` file)? I need it, because i intend to call the class from react native with callback to receive data from native code

Comment: actually, i think, i can do it using events instead... Thank you anyway, your explanation is even more than i needed :)

Comment: that is another question. but the last time i used react native, passing data between native and react native was sort of limited, i 'm not sure about it now.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would add that as of iOS 9, you no longer need to remove the observer, as the system keeps its own reference:
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/unregistering-nsnotificationcenter-observers-in-ios-9/

Comment: @Chris thanks, i didn't know that. can you edit the answer?

Comment: It's in the queue :)

Comment: Getting error: `addObserver:{myObserver} - expected expression`

Comment: you replace "{myObserver}" with your variable name, right?